# Is it possible to change the font in the Developer Powershell Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2019

I would like to set up Visual Studio 2019 to use Cascadia Code PL on Terminal Window.
I was able to set it through "Tools > Environment > Fonts and Colors" menu for Text Editor, but I wasn't able to find where to do it for Terminal.

[image: Developer PowerShell Terminal]

Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

I had the same Developer PowerShell as in you screenshot but it should be in the "Show settings for:" dropdown list:
[image]

Comment: This could be the answer I'm looking for but, the external link to an image is broken. So, who knows :-(

Comment: Image is showing up as of 08 Jun 2022, so there may have been CDN issues with SO or some such.  At any rate, going to `Tools` | `Options` | `Environment` | `Fonts and Colors`, and then picking `Terminal` from the `Show Settings For` drop-down allowed me to pick a different font for the Developer PowerShell window and it worked like a charm.  Now I just need to figure out how I can customize the cursor as well.  That block is annoying.

Comment: In my case also the image is broken. I am on my company laptop and has a VPN. If I disconnect the VPN, then the images appear back. If I connect back the VPN, the images are broken again. So check the VPN